# How to find the Consecutive Days from a list of dates or data frame

Tags: python, r, excel

I need to find consecutive days from the data frame but I am having some trouble trying to find them. I tried R, Excel, and Python but still couldn't find the solution.

My data looks like this

```
Date        PRECTOT
1982/2/1    0.1
1982/2/2    0.14
1982/2/3    0
1982/2/6    0
1982/2/7    0
1982/2/8    0
1982/2/10   0
1982/2/11   0
1982/2/12   0
1982/2/15   0.18
1982/2/16   0
1982/2/20   0.08
1982/2/21   0
1982/2/22   0
1982/2/23   0
1982/2/24   0.03
1982/2/25   0
1982/2/26   0
1982/2/27   0
1982/2/28   0
1982/3/4    0
1982/3/5    0.05
1982/3/8    0.16
1982/3/9    0
```

My expected output:

```
Date        PRECTOT  Consecutive
1982/2/1    0.1      3
1982/2/2    0.14    
1982/2/3    0   
1982/2/6    0        3
1982/2/7    0   
1982/2/8    0   
1982/2/10   0        3
1982/2/11   0   
1982/2/12   0   
1982/2/15   0.18     2
1982/2/16   0   
1982/2/20   0.08     9
1982/2/21   0   
1982/2/22   0   
1982/2/23   0   
1982/2/24   0.03    
1982/2/25   0   
1982/2/26   0   
1982/2/27   0   
1982/2/28   0   
1982/3/4    0        2
1982/3/5    0.05    
1982/3/8    0.16     2
1982/3/9    0
```

Or

```
Date        PRECTOT  Consecutive
1982/2/1    0.1      1
1982/2/2    0.14     2
1982/2/3    0        3
1982/2/6    0        1
1982/2/7    0        2
1982/2/8    0        3
1982/2/10   0        1
1982/2/11   0        2
1982/2/12   0        3
1982/2/15   0.18     1
1982/2/16   0        2
1982/2/20   0.08     1
1982/2/21   0        2
1982/2/22   0        3
1982/2/23   0        4
1982/2/24   0.03     5
1982/2/25   0        6
1982/2/26   0        7
1982/2/27   0        8
1982/2/28   0        9
1982/3/4    0        1
1982/3/5    0.05     2
1982/3/8    0.16     1
1982/3/9    0        2
```

Consecutive values can be formatted, all I need to find out Consecutive Values.
I would like to find a solution but I don't know what to do. (R/Python/Excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try an R approach using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(0, diff(as.Date(Date, "%Y/%m/%d"))) > 1)) %>% 
  mutate(Consecutive = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 24 x 3
   Date      PRECTOT Consecutive
   <chr>       <dbl>       <int>
 1 1982/2/1     0.1            1
 2 1982/2/2     0.14           2
 3 1982/2/3     0              3
 4 1982/2/6     0              1
 5 1982/2/7     0              2
 6 1982/2/8     0              3
 7 1982/2/10    0              1
 8 1982/2/11    0              2
 9 1982/2/12    0              3
10 1982/2/15    0.18           1
11 1982/2/16    0              2
12 1982/2/20    0.08           1
13 1982/2/21    0              2
14 1982/2/22    0              3
15 1982/2/23    0              4
16 1982/2/24    0.03           5
17 1982/2/25    0              6
18 1982/2/26    0              7
19 1982/2/27    0              8
20 1982/2/28    0              9
21 1982/3/4     0              1
22 1982/3/5     0.05           2
23 1982/3/8     0.16           1
24 1982/3/9     0              2
```

To export this to excel, you could use the `openxlsx` package:

```r
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(0, diff(as.Date(Date, "%Y/%m/%d"))) > 1)) %>% 
  mutate(Consecutive = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp) %>% 
  write.xlsx("my_excel_file.xlsx")
```

This gives you an Excel file like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. 
It's working. 
but it shows only in  # A Tibble
I need to convert it into a data frame and export it into an excel file
I don't know what to do.

Comment: A tibble is an improved data.frame. If you want to convert it, pipe an additional `as.data.frame()`.

Comment: For exporting to excel use the `openxlsx` package.

Comment: Hello, sorry I'm asking basic questions. what should I put inside of the bracket`()` `as.data.frame()` I googled it and watched videos but didn't understand what to do and how to get the data into excel.

Comment: @MehediHasanBhuyian I added the step to export it to Excel.

Comment: It says
 `Error in saveWorkbook(wb, file = file, overwrite = overwrite) :` 
  `argument "file" is missing, with no default`
now what should I do

Comment: On my machine this code works and creates the `xlsx`-file.

Comment: Hello **@MartinGal**
Thank you sooooo much. 
At first, it didn't work, I couldn't find why. Then I delete everything, start a new project from the first, and now it works. 
I really appreciate your help <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

I'll use `pandas`.

Suppose `df` is an input table you have and `Date` column has `pd.Timestamp` type. I want to apply `rolling` to `Date` column and it supports only operations with numeric types, so I'll transform it to nanoseconds first:

```
from operator import attrgetter

date_ns = df.Date.apply(attrgetter("value")) # df.Date.dt.value will not work :(
```

Then for each date in `Date` column i'll map `1` if the previous date in terms of `Date` column is a previous day in terms of the real calendar:

```
ONE_DAY = pd.Timedelta(days=1).value

def apply_func(x):
   if len(x) == 2 and x[1] - x[0] == ONE_DAY:
       return 1
   return 0

prev_is_prev = date_ns.rolling(2, min_periods=1).apply(apply_func)
```

All we need now is `cumsum`:

```
df["Consecutive"] = prev_is_prev.cumsum() + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's not working 
I don't know where's the problem 

I put this:

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from operator import attrgetter

bagerhatFl = pd.read_excel("mod_af_fl.xlsx")

date_ns = bagerhatFl.Date.apply(attrgetter("value")) # df.Date.dt.value will not work :(

ONE_DAY = pd.Timedelta(days=1).value

def apply_func(x):
   if len(x) == 2 and x[1] - x[0] == ONE_DAY:
       return 1
   return 0

prev_is_prev = date_ns.rolling(2, min_periods=1).apply(apply_func)

bagerhatFl["Consecutive"] = prev_is_prev.cumsum() + 1

Comment: and get this :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mahedi Hasan\PycharmProjects\PROj2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 385, in get_loc
    return self._range.index(new_key)
ValueError: 0 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's not working I don't know where's the problem 

I put this:
`import pandas as pd`
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

`from operator import attrgetter`
`bagerhatFl = pd.read_excel("mod_af_fl.xlsx")`
`date_ns = bagerhatFl.Date.apply(attrgetter("value")) # df.Date.dt.value will not work :(`
`ONE_DAY = pd.Timedelta(days=1).value`
`def apply_func(x):`
`if len(x) == 2 and x[1] - x[0] == ONE_DAY:`
`return 1`
`return 0`

`prev_is_prev = date_ns.rolling(2, min_periods=1).apply(apply_func)`

`bagerhatFl["Consecutive"] = prev_is_prev.cumsum() + 1`

Comment: and get this : 
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Mahedi Hasan\PycharmProjects\PROj2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 385, in get_loc return self._range.index(new_key) ValueError: 0 is not in range The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last):`

Comment: can you paste the full traceback, please